# How to navigate back to previous screen in another tab in React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have 4 navigation stacks Menu,Dashboard,Progress and notification.

```
export const HomeTabs = () => {
      return (
        <Tabs.Navigator
          tabBarPosition="bottom"
          initialRouteName="DashboardStack"
          screenOptions={getTabNavigationOptions}>
          <Tabs.Screen component={MenuStack} name="MenuStack" />
          {/* <Tabs.Screen component={CalendarStack} name="CalendarStack" /> */}
          <Tabs.Screen component={DashboardStack} name="DashboardStack" />
    
          <Tabs.Screen
            component={ProgressStack}
            name="ProgressStack"
            initialParams={{route_index: 0}}
          />
          <Tabs.Screen component={NotificationStack} name="NotificationStack" />
        </Tabs.Navigator>
      );
    };
```

Back navigation works normally between the screens of a particular tab, however when I switch a tab and then press back immediately it should switch to previous screen in another tab. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

write **headerShown: false** ( turn off your header navigation on screen )

```
<Tabs.Screen component={ProgressStack}
  name="ProgressStack"
  initialParams={{route_index: 0}}
  options={{
    headerShown: false,
  }}/>
```

In the component you need to accept the `{navigation}` props, after that you need to make a layout of your button component which, when clicked, will return you to the desired screen
`navigation.navigate('SCREEN')` or `navigation.back()`

Example in YOURSCREE.jsx

```
export default function YOUCOMPONENT ({navigation}) {
return(
    <SafeAreaView style={{
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('YOUR DESIRED SCREEN TO BACK')}>
            {/*Your svg or image of Arrow */}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View>
            <Text style={{fontFamily: 'mt-bold', fontSize: 18,}}>YOUR SCREEN TEXT</Text>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
   );
}
```

Comment: I dont want to define any particular screen. lets say if im at some screen in dashboard and then i switch to notification tab , on back it should go to dashboard stack but it goes to the menu stack which is the very first stack

Comment: do you mean swipe to the left or click on the 'arrow' button that you have created in the place with it ?

Comment: no swipe just go to previous tab